# Why does the platform created with for cycle go over the border limit?

Tags: c++

I've started programming just recently and I've learned the basic concepts of classes and objects and how to create them. So I decided to try and create a simple game of breakout with what I've learned so far. I've only created the main movable platform with a for cycle and make it move horizontally with the directional keys so far. I've also created a void so the platform doesn't go over the border of the screen but it doesn't work and I've tried all I could think of. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Game::Game( MainWindow& wnd )
    :
    wnd( wnd ),
    gfx( wnd )
{
}

void Game::Go()
{
    gfx.BeginFrame();   
    UpdateModel();
    ComposeFrame();
    gfx.EndFrame();
}

void Game::UpdateModel()
{
    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_RIGHT))
    {
        platform.vx += 3;
    }

    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(VK_LEFT))
    {
        platform.vx -= 3;
    }

    platform.ScreenLimit();
}

void Game::ComposeFrame()
{
    for (platform.x = 460; platform.x <= platform.w; platform.x++)
    {
        for (platform.y = 500; platform.y <= platform.h; platform.y++)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(platform.x + platform.vx, platform.y, 255, 255, 255);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the header file and source file of the class I created for the platform:

Platform.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Graphics.h"
class Platform
{
public:

    int x = 460;
    int y = 500;
    int vx = 0;
    int width = 60;
    int heigth = 10;
    int w = x + width;
    int h = y + heigth;

    void ScreenLimit();

    
private:

};
```

Platform.cpp

```
#include "Platform.h"

void Platform::ScreenLimit()
{
    const int left_base = x;
    const int right_base = w;

    if (right_base >= Graphics::ScreenWidth)
    {
        x = (Graphics::ScreenWidth - 6) - width;
    }
    else if (left_base <= 0)
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The code you posted does not compile. You are including a file "Graphics.h", but did not post the contents of this file.

Comment: The code you posted is not pure ISO C++. You seem to be using some platform-specific API. Please specify which API you are using and set the appropriate tag in your question. That way, you will attract people to your question who are watching the tag.

Comment: Is `platform.vx` supposed to be the horizontal speed of the platform? If yes, then I don't understand why I can't see any code that is updating the position of the platform based on the speed? Did you not write any such code?

Comment: Sorry for answering now. I'm currently following the basic c++ course of ChiliTomatoNoodle. The homework and any other instruction (for basic level course) that he gives are done in a file that already has classes and files, all made by him. If you want I can give you a link of where to download it or I can post here the content of the graphics class or any other class that you think may be necessary to see.

Comment: About the platform.vx thing. I use it to move the base horizontally (so it's not really the speed, I'll watch out for the naming the next time I post). in fact if you look closely it's present in the putPixel. The reason I made it is that, at first, I tried to update the x directly (x += x;) but for some reason it didn't work so I tried by adding a separate variable.

Comment: Why are you using `platform.x` and `platform.y` as loop counters? This will overwrite the values of `platform.x` and `platform.y`. Is this intended? Normally, you use a separate local variable as a loop counter.

Comment: The expression `x += x` in your last comment is equivalent to `x = x + x`, which is equivalent to `x = x * 2`. In other words, this doubles the value of `x`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I'm stupid, I meant x += 1. I'll try using local variables for the loop.

Comment: The reason why that statement doesn't work is probably because you are using `platform.x` as a loop counter in `Game::Compose`, which overwrites that member variable every time the function is called.

Comment: I think it would be easier for me to help you if you posted the link to your tutorial. So yes please, please post that link.

Comment: Please also clarify (by adding comments in your code) what the individual member variales of the `class Platform` represent.

Comment: I assume that `x` represents the horizontal coordinate of the platform (which can be changed with the arrow keys) and `y` the vertical coordinate of the platform (which is never supposed to change). However, do these coordinates refer to the middle of the platform or some edge of the platform?

Comment: I assume that `width` and `height` represent the dimensions of the platform in pixels, i.e. it is 6 times as wide as it is high. But what do `w` and `h` represent? The coordinates of the bottom-right corner?

Comment: I've made local variables for the loop, and I've changed a few things in ScreenLimit, changing only vx when the if is true. Now it finally work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice. :-) I really suggest that you reduce the number of member variables in `class Platform` to the amount that you actually require. It seems to me that you only need `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`. As stated before, I see no need for `vx` (unless you are actually storing the speed), `w` and `h`. Having more variables than you need will make your program messy and unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. This was sort of a sketch of how the program was supposed to look like. I planned on polishing it after.

Comment: If you want `platform.x` to stay within the range 0..460, then you must make sure that you never increment it or decrement it outside this range, for example by writing the following code: `platform.x -= 3; if ( platform.x < 0 ) platform.x = 0;` and in the other place `platform.x += 3; if ( platform.x > 460 ) platform.x = 460;`

Comment: Yeah, I tried something similar, and it seems to work perfectly.